# OpenVPN3: Error calling StartServiceByName... Permission Denied... as root?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apt, openvpn

I cannot figure out how it's possible that I'm getting "permission denied" as root. Something might be missing execute permission, but I cannot figure out from this error message what that might be. In any event, I followed the installation instructions exactly as written so I'm at a loss. Any suggestions on where to begin troubleshooting this?

```
root@bigboi:/home/andrew# apt install openvpn3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openvpn3
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,447 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,779 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal/main amd64 openvpn3 amd64 13~beta-1+focal [1,447 kB]
Fetched 1,447 kB in 19s (77.6 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                      
Selecting previously unselected package openvpn3.
(Reading database ... 170788 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openvpn3_13~beta-1+focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openvpn3 (13~beta-1+focal) ...
Setting up openvpn3 (13~beta-1+focal) ...
openvpn3-autoload.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
root@bigboi:/home/andrew# openvpn3 session-start --config /home/andrew/.vpn/client.ovpn
** ERROR ** Failed preparing proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for net.openvpn.v3.sessions: Failed to execute program net.openvpn.v3.sessions: Permission denied
```

Version information:

```
$ sudo openvpn3 version
OpenVPN 3/Linux v13_beta (openvpn3)
OpenVPN core 3.git:HEAD:ce0c9963 linux x86_64 64-bit
Copyright (C) 2012-2020 OpenVPN Inc. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `openvpn3`, but see if it has a verbose flag (usually `-v`)

Comment: Thank you @Panki. It did not have a verbose option, but that did inspire me to include information from the `version` subcommand.