# Failed to fetch https://packages.openvpn.net/.../dists/lunar/InRelease 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, openvpn, deb

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 on a I9 cpu + Nvidia Geforce RTX 2080 ti and the driver 545 right now. I would like to install the OpenVPN 3 client on my Ubuntu,but I'm not able to install the repository :

This is the guide that I'm following :

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux

I did several tries :

1)

```
# apt install apt-transport-https curl
# mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings    ### This might not exist in all distributions
# curl -sSfL https://packages.openvpn.net/packages-repo.gpg >/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc
# echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu lunar main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
# apt update

Err:7 https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu lunar InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.18.110.96 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.openvpn.net/.../dists/lunar/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.18.110.96 443]
E: The repository 'https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu lunar InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(manpage for repository creation and user configuration details).
```

2. 

```
# apt install apt-transport-https curl
# mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings    ### This might not exist in all distributions
# curl -sSfL https://packages.openvpn.net/packages-repo.gpg >/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc
# echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian bookworm main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
# apt update

Get:8 https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [3,996 B]
Fetched 9,833 B in 1s (7,890 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian bookworm InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

3. 

```
# apt install apt-transport-https curl
# mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings    ### This might not exist in all distributions
# curl -sSfL https://packages.openvpn.net/packages-repo.gpg >/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc
# echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu jammy main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
# apt update

Err:7 https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.18.110.96 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.openvpn.net/.../dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 104.18.110.96 443]
E: The repository 'https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(manpage for repository creation and user configuration details).
```

how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions:

> Replace the DISTRIBUTION part in the command below using the release
> name from the table above to set up the apt source listing:
>
> ```shell
> # echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn.asc] https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian DISTRIBUTION main" >>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
> ```

didn't tell to replace `debian` by `ubuntu`, only to replace `DISTRIBUTION` by (for your case) `lunar` (or actually `mantic` to match Ubuntu 23.10 if it's really available).

The difference can be seen like this:

```shell
# curl --head https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/ubuntu/dists/lunar/InRelease
HTTP/2 403 
date: Sun, 12 Nov 2023 19:13:45 GMT
content-type: application/xml
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 83d0137377604ae8e59d0712f3ef6fe2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: CDG50-P4
x-amz-cf-id: laB_0LYJFnyy0606N7PZLa-0W5RrIIcV8WhY94yEJW9L5P11wNpNlA==
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 8251180dfaa4d712-CDG
```

```shell
# curl --head https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian/dists/lunar/InRelease
HTTP/2 200 
date: Sun, 12 Nov 2023 19:14:17 GMT
content-type: binary/octet-stream
content-length: 5834
last-modified: Fri, 20 Oct 2023 12:38:14 GMT
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
x-amz-version-id: bY4e_Bp3DQ08SopZYWEh_Npc9FlsW9sW
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "ff8c6bcfcb12d04e55111e1b27e8b6d4"
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 0df1e08a236a7f5d1f4f9f78bdb4bb82.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: CDG50-P4
x-amz-cf-id: lq2UQ8jH4jAAXflV75X4EkwiGR14qpzv5YD29ma4GesxmLNGFSoDNg==
age: 31637
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 825118d80af70051-CDG
```

```shell
# curl --head https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian/dists/mantic/InRelease
HTTP/2 200 
date: Sun, 12 Nov 2023 19:20:55 GMT
content-type: binary/octet-stream
content-length: 5835
last-modified: Fri, 20 Oct 2023 12:38:14 GMT
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
x-amz-version-id: X9oVa0sKru7sF5UfEl17Aor_StRj.80H
accept-ranges: bytes
etag: "ad10f89d73c40adfc3ab9eba92befdab"
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
via: 1.1 03e404344c9f165c7468cdb109674f3a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: CDG50-P4
x-amz-cf-id: larhe4f3E2Y_fdbNygPShe0DiYfJZS7PxUp_SxfEsIm41Nox1fr41Q==
age: 17906
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 82512292284e019e-CDG
```

Details do matter.

Still it would have helped better if the error returned was 404 (not found) rather than 403 (forbidden).

Comment: By the way to know which URL to check with `curl` I added the repository (without caring for the key, I don't intend to install from it) and ran: `apt-get --print-uris update | grep openvpn3 | grep Release`.

Comment: # openvpn3 session-start --dco true --config vpn.zrh.witopia.net.ovpn
** ERROR ** Failed preparing proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for net.openvpn.v3.sessions: Failed to execute program net.openvpn.v3.sessions: Permission denied

Comment: @Marietto I solved the problem about *installing* the openvpn3 repository and packages. If you have a problem about *using* it, that's something else.

Comment: yes,I've installed,but it gives the error "permission denied". Should I open another post to solve this ?

Comment: I can't tell if you should immediately open an other question for this (you might take time to research it first), but it sure doesn't match your original question. Since it's something new, marked as "beta" (meaning: bugs can exist), you might not have someone familiar with it and possible packaging bugs.

Comment: @Marietto somebody had this problem 2 years ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655496/openvpn3-error-calling-startservicebyname-permission-denied-as-root (no answer).  It's possible that some of the commands are intended to not be run as root (considering they are insisting on privilege separation etc.) I have no more idea about this.

Comment: I get the same error if I run it not as root.

Comment: I'm getting this error : Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.openvpn.net/openvpn3/debian lunar (and mantic) InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)

Comment: That means you can't use a 32bits version of the tool. Is your OS 32bits or 64bits? if 64bits then it doesn't concern you.